# compresses and decompresses the file with each of the "compress, gzip, bzip2 and zip"

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to write a script that takes a filename as argument and then compresses and decompresses the file with each of the programs, `compress, gzip, bzip2` and `zip`. At each stage, it notes the size of the file before and after compression. Finally, it displays a list showing the compression program, uncompressed size, compressed size and compression ratio (up to 1 place of decimal). I want the list be ordered by the compression achieved, with figures for the most efficient compression featuring at the top. Any comments or helps would greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why?  This has to be homework, right?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you have any more specific questions?

Comment: Break it down into smaller steps you can do yourself at the shell prompt: find out the file size, compress the file, find out its compressed size, calculate the ratio, then put that into a script.  Use a `for COMPRESSION in compress gzip bzip2 zip; do ...; done` to work through the compression programs, then put a pipe to sort -n on the appropriate output column.  Come back with specific problems for the bits you can't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$1"

# Original file size
orig_size=$(stat -c'%s' $file)

# Get sizes
gzip_size=$(gzip -c "$file" | wc -c)    
# Repeat for other compression types...

# Get ratios
gzip_ratio=$(echo "scale=1; 100 * ($orig_size - $gzip_size) / $orig_size" | bc)
# Repeat for others...

# Unsorted output
echo "gzip $orig_size $gzip_size $gzip_ratio" >> unsorted.txt
# Repeat for others...

# Create sorted list
sort -n -r +3 -4 unsorted.txt > sorted.txt
cat sorted.txt # Print sorted list
```

Comment: I think `orig_size` should not point to `${file}.gz` but only to `${file}`.

Comment: @Danosaure: Thanks, well spotted! Fixed.

Comment: to get the gzipped size, I'd just write `gzip_size=$( gzip -c "$file" | wc -c )` instead of actually writing the "$file.gz" to disk.

Comment: @glenn: Nice tip. I'll add it to the source.

Comment: Thanks, you are the best. It's very understandable with the comments.